# rational rhapsody - build error

Tags: build, rhapsody, ibm-rational

Im using IBM Rational Rhapsody for Java 8.1.1

**Whenever I try to compile/build/run any project I get such an error:**

```
Building ------------  MainDefaultComponent.class   ------------
Executing: "C:\Users\Adam\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.1.1\Share\etc\jdkmake.bat" DefaultComponent.bat build
MySQL is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
MySQL is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file
program wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.
compiling JAVA source files

Build Done
```

I've tried running sample projects and creating a new simple one and it didn't work.

I've changed JavaLocation in jdkmake.bat, its not about javalocation I think.
Any ideas?

@edit
Reinstalled jdk, jre and rational and now its working... weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused because MySQL isn't in your PATH environmental variable.